# Array null in GUID

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array and i try to push items to array but it's shows me array is null.
In my scenario,my car model listbox(id is carmod) shows this id's

```
<option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001">BMW</option>
<option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002">Maruti</option>
<option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003">Wagon</option>
```

My Code

```
var Intlst = [];
$("#carmod").each(function (index, item) {
      debugger;
      Intlst.push(item.value);//in here it shows me " " (double quotes)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$("#carmod option").each(function (index, item) {
      Intlst.push(item.value);
});
```

In this way you will select all the `option` elements under the html element with id `carmod`. As it is now, your selector doesn't select all the option elements in the select html element.

Comment: @UDP - you say *thanks* by upvoting helpful answers and upvoting and clicking the checkmark by the answer that was the most helpful and making it green!

Answer (score 1):

`.each` works on the jQuery object which is array-like, not each `option`. Refine your selector or use `$.find`

```
$("#carmod option").each(function (index, item) {
  Intlst.push(item.value);
});
```

using `$.find`

```
$("#carmod").find("option").each(function (index, item) {
  Intlst.push(item.value);
});
```